# How to write a code that prints odd-even numbers using for-each loop on an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

I have wrote a code that is supposed to print Odd and even numbers from an Array using for-each loop in Java but unfortunately it shows

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 22"
```

Even if some of the answers are printed in the compiler, it's not as it's supposed to be.
Such as: the output would be like this:

```
Even numbers in the Array are:
10
6
4
2
.
.
```

but it shows like this:

```
Even numbers in the Array are:
10
14
4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 22
```

Can anybody help?

Here is my code for your reference.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num = {1,3,9,10,6,5,4,2,22,14,15,7,8};

        System.out.println("Even numbers in the Array are:");
        for (int i : num) {
            if (num[i] % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(num[i]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The Odd numbers in the Array are:");
        for (int i : num) {
            if (num[i] % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.println(num[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have wrote a code that is supposed to print Odd and even numbers
> from an Array using for-each loop in Java but unfortunately it shows
>
> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
> 22".

That is because you are using the elements of the array as indices themselves of the array. It fails at 22 because it is the first value in the array that is higher than the size of the array.

You have index-base loops

```
for(int i=0; i<num.length; i++){
    if( num[i]%2 ==0) {
        System.out.println(num[i]);
    }
}
```

and you have (among others) *enhanced for loops* that allows you to directly iterate over the content of (for example) an array without having to explicitly specify an index.

**for-each Loop Sytnax**

[The syntax of the Java for-each loop is:](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/enhanced-for-loop)

```
for(dataType item : array) {
    ...
}
```

> Here,
>
> array - an array or a collection 
> item - each item of array/collection is assigned to this variable dataType 
> the data type - of the array/collection array/collection

This allows to make the code more concise and also less error prone:

```
for(int n : num) {
    if(n%2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

This loop is very useful because a lot of the times one wants to iterate though all the elements of the array without really caring about the index aside from when accessing the element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i : num)
```

here "i" is not an index of your array, this is exactly the element,
so you don't need to obtain a value in a such way

```
num[i]
```

it is enough to refer just in a such way

```
i
```

so it would be better to not use the variable name "i" in such context but

```
for (number: numbers)
```

for example instead